# SSL works with browser, wget, and curl, but fails with git

Tags: apache, git, ssl, redmine

I have a website I am using to host redmine and several git repositories

This works perfectly for http, but I can't clone with https, i.e.

```
git clone http://mysite.com/git/test.git
```

works fine, but

```
git clone https://mysite.com/git/test.git
```

fails

The strange thing is that https seems to work for everything else I have tested. If I open

```
https://mysite.com/git/test.git
```

in a browser (tested in chrome and firefox), I get no errors or warnings. I can also

```
curl https://mysite.com/git/test.git
wget https://mysite.com/git/test.git
```

both of which work with no complaints or warnings.

Here is the verbose output from git:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://user@mysite.com/test/test.git
Cloning into test...
Password:
* Couldn't find host mysite.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to mysite.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connected to mysite.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* found 157 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
* Closing connection #0
* Couldn't find host mysite.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to mysite.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connected to mysite.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* found 157 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
* Closing connection #0
error: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none while accessing https://user\
@mysite.com/test/test.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Here is the verbose output from curl, with the personal info changed:

```
* About to connect() to mysite.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to mysite.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; <... cut my certs info ...>
*        start date: 2011-10-18 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2013-10-17 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: mysite.com matched
*        issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.22 librtmp/2.3
> Host: mysite.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 21:39:54 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
< Last-Modified: Fri, 14 Oct 2011 03:20:01 GMT
< ETag: "8209c-87-4af39bb89ccac"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 135
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Pad: avoid browser bug
<
<p>Welcome to the mysite.com<p/>
* Connection #0 to host mysite.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

The only difference I can see is that git seems to be using an explicit CAfile while curl uses the whole directory? I'm new to ssl (at least on the admin side), so I'm not sure what this means or how I could configure git to work the same way as curl.

I am using git 1.7.5.4 and apache 2.2.14 on Ubuntu 10.04. I've tried cloning from 3 different linux hosts (including another account on the server itself), and nothing works.

I've also used the openssl tool to verify my cert on the server:

```
$openssl verify -purpose sslserver -CAfile chain.crt signed.pem 
signed.pem: OK
```

This may be related to the bug https://bugs.maemo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4953 but it seems different because I am not getting any warning or errors in any other program.

It may be worth mentioning that I am using gitolite and [redmine_git_hosting](https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting) using smart http to do authentication over https. I don't think any of this is at fault though, because the problem exists even if I just stick an otherwise working bare repo in /var/www and access it directly. Also, git over ssh (with and without gitolite) works.

Please let me know if you have any idea what might be wrong or if you'd like some more info. I'd really prefer to get ssl working properly, as opposed to forcing everyone to disable certificate checking in git, although that is a current workaround.

Thanks for reading this long post!

Comment: Note that with Git 2.5+, you will be able to specify a cipher list for curl to use. That could help. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30442395/6309

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that this was a gnuTLS issue. gnuTLS is order sensitive, while openssl is not. I re-ordered the certificates in my intermediate cert file and the problem went away

Comment: Which intermediate cert file are you talking about? The server-side apache cert chain or a client-side file? If the second, which one?

Comment: It was the server-side intermediate certificate file

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm getting a similar answer. Can you provide more details on how to do this?

Comment: This was so long ago so my memory is very rusty on this. What I vaguely remember is that someone gave me a cert file to put on my server. This was signed by a top level SSL authority and provided ssl on the server I was hosting. The solution was to go to that file (which lived in apache config somewhere) and look at it. It had two certs in it, and I just re-ordered them and then it started working (after restarting apache)

Answer (score 11):

XCondE's answer will address the problem, but turning off security warnings always feels like a bad idea. If you're running on an ubuntu box, then the issue may be that the CA certificate for your web server isn't in the /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file. I ran into this with a git server hosted on a web server with a SSL certificate signed by www.incommon.org.

You can add the intermediate certificate to your ca-certificates file, as follows:

```
wget http://cert.incommon.org/InCommonServerCA.crt
openssl x509 -inform DER -in InCommonServerCA.crt -out incommon.pem
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt incommon.pem > ca-certs2.crt
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.bak
sudo cp ca-certs2.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

There's a good discussion of what's going on behind the scenes here:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this error with one of my Comodo PositiveSSL certificates and was able to fix it by changing the order of the intermediate certificates.

After ordering the certificate, I was provided with the following files:

- Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- PositiveSSL Wildcard Certificate - STAR_mydomain_com.crt

Originally, the order of certificates in the `.crt` I was providing to Nginx was as follows:

- PositiveSSL Wildcard Certificate - STAR_mydomain_com.crt
- Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

However, I reversed the order of the last two certificates and Git no longer throws verification errors.

Answer (score 3):

git uses gnutls for this stuff, which requires the CA be specified.  This can be done with per-respository with:

```
git config http.sslcapath <path to CA directory>
```

OR

```
git config http.sslcainfo <path to CA cert>
```

You can also specify --system or --global.

Answer (score 0):

export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1

From http://blog.breadncup.com/2011/06/09/skip-git-ssl-verification/

WARNING: as some people mentioned, this disables verification, leaving you open to a sleuth of security issues.  You shouldn't rely on it long-term but, in a pinch, it will get the job done.

Comment: It is like having problems with unlocking doors being resolved by leaving the doors unlocked for all the time. There are some related security risks.

Comment: This does not work for me @ debian wheezy, git 1.7.10.4, still gnutls_handshake() failed :(.

Comment: Please do not ever do this.  Without verification you are basically asking git to put malware on your system.

Comment: please add a warning.... this is easy to do but it may be a bad idea for some users

Comment: I added a warning in case it's not completely obvious that this isn't the best solution.  Sometimes, however, you just want to get around a problem  so it's here as a reference since I've found myself in the situation before.

Comment: This is very useful when operating on private networks when the server has not been set up correctly, but when the user has no control over it.  As a variable that only lasts as long as your TTY session, it's vastly preferable to changing global git configuration values. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you didn't configure correctly Apache

You may have to add your server name to the Apache configuration file
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf, e.g.:

```
ServerName demo.personalserver.com
```

From: https://www.progclub.org/blog/2014/09/03/gnutls_handshake-failed-using-git/#comment-96924